# Replace nan with value from other column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

df:

| ColumnA | ColumnB |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | nan |
| 2 | 20 |
| 3 | 50 |
| 4 | nan |
| 5 | nan |
| 6 | 100 |
| 7 | 1 |
| 8 | 2 |

If the ColumnB contain a 'nan' value, how can I replace it with the corresponding ColumnA value?

I need to get the following Dataset:

df2:

| ColumnA | ColumnB |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 20 |
| 3 | 50 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 5 |
| 6 | 100 |
| 7 | 1 |
| 8 | 2 |

I have tried with an if Statment, but it only replace the first value.

Comment: you could fill the NaN in your column B using column A. For example:  ```df.ColumnB.fillna(df['ColumnA'])```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"ColumnA":range(9)[1:],"ColumnB":[None, 20, 50, None, None, 100, 1, 2]})
print(df)
df['ColumnB'] = df.apply(lambda row: row["ColumnA"] if (row["ColumnB"] is None) or np.isnan(row["ColumnB"]) else row["ColumnB"], axis=1)
print(df)
```